# Converting Dates to Quarters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, aggregate, altair

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MslaM.jpg)

I want to convert dates to quarters but I only want to display quarters once in altair because it would jam my x-axis column.

Is there a way to aggregate this?

The data/code is

```
data[['date', 'percentage']]

alt.Chart(df_avg)
                .mark_line(strokeDash=[5, 5])
                .encode(
                    x=alt.X("date:N", title="Date", sort=None),
                    y=alt.Y(
                        "value:Q",
                        axis=alt.Axis(format=y_axis_format),
                        scale=alt.Scale(domain=y_axis_scale),
                        title=title,
                    ),
                    color=alt.Color("series:N", title="Legend", scale=alt.Scale(domain=domain, range=range_)),
                )
            )
```

EDIT:

[Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trAfH.png)

The above shows the actual data. I'm trying the resampling method of df['month'].resample('Q', label = 'right') and I'm getting an error that says

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex
```

How can I alter this data so it works out with the resampling method?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the [DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method. You can see the various 'rule' values [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects). In particular you probably want 'Q' (calendar quarter end) or 'QS' (calendar quarter start).

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, I cannot comment for sure what is happening. But if your data is in the correct format,
using the US employment dataset available in Altair, what you are looking for will look something like this

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.us_employment()
# renaming the date column to avoid confusion
source = source.rename(columns={'month':'date'})

chart = alt.Chart(
    source,
).transform_calculate(
    # create a new variable xq which is of the format year_Q#
    # looks messy, but couldn't come up with a cleaner way of creating this
    quater = 'quarter(datum.date)',
    year = "year(datum.date)", 
    xq = "datum.year + '_Q' + datum.quater"
).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("xq:O", title=""),
    y=alt.Y("mean_y:Q", title="Change in non-farm employment (in thousands)"),
).transform_aggregate(
    mean_y='mean(nonfarm_change)', # replace it with your y value
    groupby=["xq"] # group by the new quater variable
)
chart.properties(width=500, height=200)
```

[image]